# Unable to reference data() in VUEjs Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I get error when referencing data() in export. It says, that property does not exist. What am I doing wrong? VueJS version 2.

This is data:

```
<script lang="ts">
  
export default {
  data() : {
  item: Array<Number> 
  key: Number
  keyy: Number
  } {
  return {
    item: [],
    key: 0,
    keyy: 0,
    };
  },
```

Here i want to reference it in same export default:

```
methods: {
      async para(value: any){
        this.key=value.target.value   //Here i get error
    },
      async paraa(value: any){
        this.keyy = value.target.value    //Here i get error
    },
    async openChannels() {
      const randomArray = [0,2]
      this.item.push(randomArray[0])  //Here i get error
    }
}
}
    </script>
```

The error I am getting is:

Property 'key' does not exist on type '{ para(value: any): Promise; paraa(value: any): Promise; openChannels(): Promise; }'

Property 'keyy' does not exist on type '{ para(value: any): Promise; paraa(value: any): Promise; openChannels(): Promise; }'

Property 'item' does not exist on type '{ para(value: any): Promise; paraa(value: any): Promise; openChannels(): Promise; }'

Thanks for the help.

Ps: My vetur extension does not show any errors. I get these only when compiling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want TypeScript support you need to use `defineComponent`

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
...
})
```

I would recommend [Volar](https://Name:%20Vue%20Language%20Features%20(Volar)%20Id:%20johnsoncodehk.volar%20Description:%20Language%20support%20for%20Vue%203%20Version:%200.34.10%20Publisher:%20Johnson%20Chu%20VS%20Marketplace%20Link:%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) instead of Vetur.

I would also recommend defining the types closer to the actual values:

```js
data() {
  return {
    item: [] as Array<Number>,
    key: 0 as Number,
    keyy: 0 as Number,
    };
  },
```

---

#### Old answer

randomArray is not defined, you are probably missing `const` or `let`

```js
const randomArray = [0,2] // <--
```

You are missing a `}` at the end

```html
  }
} // <--
</script>
```

After these edits, your code should work: [Live demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Oh sorry, in code there is I forgot to add it here. That is not a problem unfortunately EDIT: edited it

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, but again my error, I replaced code with this simple example and forgot to add const. This is now also edited as it is not related to main error.

Comment: See my updated answer on usage of `defineComponent` for typescript support.

Comment: Following changes result in same errors as well as new one -  Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'defineComponent'

Comment: I fixed it with your help and install of vue composition api library. Thanks for your time